# Why does my command 'cd /var/www && php bin/console doctrine:database:create' not work when being passed in ssh?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, vagrant

Would anyone know why if i run:

`vagrant ssh -- -t cd /var/www && php bin/console doctrine:database:create`

I get:

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`

But if i vagrant ssh and then run:

`cd /var/www && php bin/console doctrine:database:create`

It works!?

Comment: shouldnt it be " -c cd /var/www/..." instead of "-t" ?

Comment: I don't think so as that give me: `Unknown cipher type 'cd'`

Comment: okay, then i dont know, i just followed the man page https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/ssh.html

Comment: sorry, you were right. I tried again with `vagrant  ssh -c 'cd /var/www && php bin/console doctrine:database:create'` and it worked... when I got the error last time I had tried `vagrant ssh -- -c cd /var/www && php bin/console doctrine:database:create`. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed with

```
vagrant ssh -c 'cd /var/www && php bin/console doctrine:database:create'
```

Thank you [John Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1712905/john-smith)